# I installed rails two days ago and it worked great, why the sudden disappearance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, github

I am following the Ruby on Rails tutorial by Michael Hartl
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/

I installed rails, ruby, all the gems necessary and configured heroku and github two days ago. I came back today and nothing is working. I'm using Mac OS X 10.7.2 (Lion). Could it have something to do with the fact I switched to using terminal instead of Iterm today (so I could easily change the colors). Now when I try in Iterm nothing works either.

Specifically the problem right now is it appears rails can't be found because it is giving me the error message "Rails is not currently installed on this system" despite the fact it is. Now I've started installing rails again but I'm afraid it is just going to happen again and installing rails takes awhile. Thanks for the help.

The first problem I noticed was when I tried to rename my first_app again with heroku rename I got the error

```
!  Invalid path.
!  Syntax is: git@heroku.com:<app>.git where <app> is your app's name.
```

despite the fact it worked two days ago. I assume the missing rails and inability to use heroku (I reinstalled that to but still received the error) is something to do with paths not getting set right. I read about symilinks but don't know how to form them or what to form them between as in the finder I can't find rails. Thanks again.

Just got the error

```
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
actionpack requires rack (~> 1.3.5, runtime)
```

used sudo gem install rack, now rails seems to be installing okay, still wondering what happened though...

Rails still doesn't work:

```
$ rails
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:230:in `activate': can't activate rack (~> 1.3.5, runtime) for ["actionpack-3.1.3", "rails-3.1.3"], already activated rack-1.4.0 for ["rack-cache-1.1", "actionpack-3.1.3", "rails-3.1.3"] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:246:in `activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:246:in `activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1056:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/rails:18
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also got the same error.

I'm believe its because of rack gem versions.

If you give the command **gem list rack**

Its displays all the rack gems versions, after that I uninstalled all rack versions and run the bundle command. It solved my problem.

I believe its because if you specify a rack version in Gemfile and if it contrails a version greater than that, it my causes error.

So try to uninstall all the rack gems and run bundle command.

Hope it may help.

Comment: ended up reinstalling everything to get it to work but your solutions might've worked

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cd your_app_directory
bundle install
gem install heroku
git add remote heroku git@heroku.com:<YOUR_HEROKU_APP_NAME>.git
heroku status --app <YOUR_HEROKU_APP_NAME>
```

Assuming all is well, this should result in you being reconnected to your application

Answer (score 0):

I assume I had the same problem.
In my case it was that, when I wrote "gem list rack", there was:

rack 1.4.0
rack 1.3.6
...

It solved it for me with:
sudo gem uninstall rack
   ->   Deleted 1.4.0

Now it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

How I solved this issue but for a newer version was to first uninstall the existing version of Rack.

Go to command terminal and enter

```
sudo gem uninstall rack
```

Then you install the version of Rack that you are alerted to as needing. In my case it was 1.4.5

[image]

but in your case the command would be

```
sudo gem install rack -v 1.3.5
```

Anyone reading this who needs a different version, can visit the following site for updated code snippet

[all versions of rack](http://rubygems.org/gems/rack/versions/)

Make sure that you enter `sudo` prior to the `gem install` then `-v` to indicate version followed by the version you want (for example) `1.3.5` or per your need.